# Common.Logging metadata on specific types of log targets

Tags: c#, logging, common.logging

I want to use Common.Logging to perform 2 different functions:

Standard logging (this happened at this time under these circustances)... this goes into a specific table.
Targeted logging (this workflow component experienced these sorts of events)... this goes into a different table with associated metadata.

Setting up Standard Logging is easy, but I need metadata associated with the second type, (workflow id, step number, that sort of thing).  With NLog, I'd pass that along in a `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` method; I'm thinking something similar must exist for Common.Logging but I can't see how to capture metadata in Common.Logging and pass the information to the `LoggerFactoryAdapter` to be rendered.

Is there a mechanism for doing this, or is it unsupported?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118626/dynamically-setting-a-log4net-property-using-common-logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked Common.Logging and added this functionality.

See [GitHub project](https://github.com/DannyVarod/common-logging) or [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.DV).

I also submitted a pull request for returning the changes to the main branch/project.

Comment: That, sir, is pretty awesome.